# Importing a CSV file/data into Teradata SQL Assistant without connecting first

Tags: csv, import, teradata-sql-assistant, import-csv, importdata

Without connecting first (using a user name, password, etc.), is it possible to import a CSV file into Teradata SQL Assistant, and to start querying that data?

Comment: Do you mean query and filter the data straight from the CSV file? Or just preview the data before importing it?

Comment: Hi, I would like to query and filter the data from the CSV file

Comment: SQL Assistant is not a query "engine" that can actually execute queries, it can only pass requests / return responses from some external database.

Comment: hmm I think I could write queries, I just need to import the csv file which I'm not able to do atm - when I click on "import data" nothing happens

Comment: Import Data is a "mode toggle". If you run an INSERT query with `?` parameter markers while Import Data is on, it will prompt you to select the input file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - could you tell me the exact query to write?

Comment: Along the lines of `INSERT someTable(Col1,Col2,Col3) VALUES(?,?,?);` - one `?` for each column. You would first need to to have created "someTable", of course.